# Is the product of unipotent radicals of opposite Borels a closed immersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reductive-groups, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a scheme $S$ and let $B \subset G$ and $B' \subset G$ be opposite Borel subgroups with their unipotent radicals $U \subset B \subset G$ and $U' \subset B' \subset G$. Thanks to the theory of the big open cell $U' \times T \times U$, the multiplication map $U \times U' \rightarrow G$ is an immersion (as one checks étale locally on $S$ to make $G$ split). Is this multiplication map actually a **closed** immersion?

I have checked some references (SGA3, Bruhat-Tits, Conrad, etc) but couldn't find this, perhaps I missed it. I would appreciate a detailed explanation or, especially, a counterexample.

Comment: For $G= GL_n$, the image is the set where the determinant of the top-left $k \times k$ submatrix is $1$ for all $k$ from $1$ to $n$, making it indeed closed.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Is your group scheme split over $S$?  Is it at least quasi-split?  If not, please specify what you mean by "Borel subgroup" and "unipotent radical".

Comment: Will's comment generalizes to split groups over any field: For any $G$-rep $V$, let $V^U$ and $V_{U'}$ be the $U$-invariants and the $U'$-covariants. Then any $g$ in $G$ induces a map $V^U \hookrightarrow V \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} V \twoheadrightarrow V_{U'}$, and $g$ is in $U' \times U$ if and only if, for all $V$, the maps $V^U \to V_{U'}$ induced by $g$ and by $\text{Id}$ coincide. (Will's criterion is to look at $V = \bigwedge^k (\mathbb{C}^n)$, in which case the invariants and covariants are $1$-dimensional, and the map is the $k \times k$ minor he mentions.)

Comment: For non-fields and non-split groups, I am not sure what "Borel" and "unipotent radical" mean.

Comment: These terms are standard for any reductive group scheme over any base scheme $S$ and were defined in SGA 3, Expose XXVI. By working etale locally on $S$, the question, of course, reduces to the case of a split $G$ (with $S$ still arbitrary).

Comment: Up to finite isogeny, every split reductive group scheme is a product of a multiplicative group scheme and a split semisimple group scheme.  So assume that the group scheme is split and semisimple.  Then there exists a morphism of group schemes to $\textbf{GL}_n$ that is a closed immersion and such that the inverse image of the upper triangular matrices is a unipotent radical of a Borel.  Thus, the $\textbf{GL}_n$ case computed by @WillSawin implies the result in general.

Comment: . . . To see that, just apply the Lie-Kolchin theorem to any faithful linear representation.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. For the embedding into $\mathbf{GL}_n$, one also needs to arrange that the chosen opposite Borel (whose choice is not unique) corresponds to the lower triangular matrices. Can this always be done?

Comment: That is a good point.  If we use the adjoint representation as the faithful representation, certainly we can make the result hold for *some* opposite Borel.  As you say, there are multiple Coxeter elements, so I am not sure if we can arrange this for every opposite Borel.